# Design of 13.56MHz RF generator circuit for driving capacitively coupled plasma

Tags: mosfet, rf, impedance, discharge

As the title suggests I've set out to design a modestly (300W?) powered RF generator for driving a plasma reactor.

Despite wanting to think my RF knowledge is good enough, the past week I spent looking through internet forums, circuit diagrams and research papers yielded more questions than
answers.

I've sketched out this circuit, a common source NMOS amplifier

[image: base circuit]

- **Problem 1, What should the output impedance be?**

There are 3 obvious requirements

1. Transfer ~300W to load
2. Minimize power lost to heat
3. Avoid damage to Q1

What impact does impedance choice have on all 3?

Is it only matching that matters so I should go with 50 because it's common, or are there any advantages to maybe 5Ohm or 1kOhm?

- **Problem 2, How to make Zout the desired value?**

Assuming Zout=50Ohm, is this circuit correct? The inductor from 12V to drain should have ~51Ohm at 13.56MHz according to online RLC calculator.

It's in series with the output so I'd assume this is what I want to have to load see Z=50Ohm.

What about the fact that Zout has high inductive reactance, do I have to put a capacitor in series with the load to bring the reactance closer to zero? Can this mismatch be used to regulate power?

- **Problem 3, How do I match Zout to Zload if the latter if unknown/changing?**

Or, do I even have to match it, if not doing it can serve some other purpose like mentioned above.

- **Problem 4, How do I ignite the plasma and avoid damage to Q1**

I'd like to reference this post
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/298561
by Dan Mills

> This can actually be very useful in plasma systems as it allow you for example to arrange for the open circuit at startup to be transformed to a short circuit at the generator to provide lots of volts for ignition.

I don't know if for RF systems the Vpeak required for ignition is lower than for DC systems but for the latter it seems close to 1kV.

That would surely damage the mosfet (any IRFXXX rated 100-400V), is there a way to have the high voltage between the load and LC network and not have it reach the mosfet drain?

Comment: 300W is not what I'd call modest. You're doing cool things :)

Comment: What's the equivalent circuit of the load?

Comment: @MarcusMüller  It's not a hard requirement, 100W would probably be a minimum. Industrial systems work from 1kW to 10kW hence the "modesty"

Comment: @Andyaka Don't really know. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/524408 proposes a series RC circuit with parallel diodes but as a simplified model you can assume a series RC circuit

Comment: Your circuit should show that load arrangement <-- it makes a big difference in the analysis. Not everyone has access to that document and anyway, the equivalent circuit is the important thing and not the document (even if I could read it). Please amend your question. Additionally, the use of a simulator would be very important here in designing the circuit. Do you use one? If not then, I urge you to do so and bite the initial learning-curve bullet.

Comment: In 300W plasma drivers I've seen, the driver is designed for 50 ohm load, allowing 50-ohm coax (and connectors) to feed power to the plasma chamber, where a tuning network resides. Some tuning networks are hand-twiddled, modern ones are motor-driven auto-tuners. The 300W amplifier should survive both shorts and open-circuits for a short time while the tuner tunes - most vulnerable during this period.

Comment: I remember that for that same kind of "work" (not CW, vapor plasma deposition) ... I began using an IRG4PH50UD_IR (IGBT, 1200 V, 45 A) under pulse conditions. I did not was able to use a "plasma model" ... because there was no one ... Even the physicist did not know how to model it (we tested 10-100 us pulses at 1 kHz). Later, it was tested under ~10 MW pulses (~ 1 kV & 1-10 kA ) ... Cooling by the circulation of pressurized cold water.

Comment: @glen_geek confirmed for 50 Ohm ... Test begins at low power for tuning ... then full power.

Comment: @Antonio51 This! Thank you Antonio, I'm sure this is the correct course of action, I'll have to make a fixed 50Ohm generator. Can you explain how is the power regulated without changing the impedance?

Comment: Is this something as https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/298550/impedance-matching-network-and-power-transfer-to-the-load/298561#298561

Comment: Will try with a old push-pull schematic (transformer, MOSFETs) driven at 13.56 MHz. Add later in an answer.

Comment: You don't detail the reactor setup, but could you adapt an off the shelf induction lamp ballast? They can be had upto 1KW, including cheap Chinese option, and whilst there operating frequency is typically 250kHz, they are simple to couple if you can setup you chamber in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can begin with a schematic example like this one.
MOSFETs type can be changed for a "faster" and "big power" type (SiC).
Notice the use of a lambda/4 length line ...
Made with [microcap v12](https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110), interactive mode.

NB: all classical tests and checking need to be done (Voltages, currents and powers ...)

[image]

And results when a 50 Ohm load is used ...
NB: Voltage of 60 V peak. Averaged Power: 27 W.  Input power: 83 W.

[image]

And when the line is "not" loaded (use of 550 Ohm).
NB: Voltage of 180 V peak. Averaged RF Power: 2.7 W. Input power: 108 W.

[image]

Tried a short circuit. Input power: 38 W.
All seems ok ...

Comment: Looks like class-D amplifier, but I don't see how L4 is coupled to the main circuit. What kind of spice sim is that?

Comment: L4 is coupled to L3 through the"coupling" device  K4, value Kc=0.95 (high right in the first picture). microcap v12,  http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm

Comment: Right I see it now, it's K1 (L3 L4). What about K2? Why is there coupling between L1 and L2? Is that a center tapped inductor?

Comment: Yes, it is a center tapped transformer. The value of the inductor can be "large" (1 mH -> 10 mH). Note that current through it can be "high"( some Amps). Check all.

Comment: Link to microcap v12 is now https://archive.org/details/mc12cd_202110

Answer (score 0):

For plasma ignition the two type of systems had been traditionally used. First was the vacuum tube circuits exploiting the parallel resonant tank. Thus tube having anode voltage 1000-1500 V but max 50 mA (x twice at push-pull topology) in resonance get the Q fold larger amperage and Class-H plasma (means ICP) is harvested. Later the transistor circuits won, and yet the several kilovolts is available, for example at Behlke, but normally 100 MHz in combination with over few hundred Volts is the damn rarity at the markets. Therefore the SERIAL tank is customarily used, means Clapp circuit, where at high enough capacitor Q-factor (strange, bt here in contrast with all other electronics the capacitor loss is dominating over inductor loss) the 3...5...8 kV may be harvested on the resonant tank elements, whilst the current stays unchanged, ca 1A....5A....20A.Logical, that 20A*3000V is very much, but kV is needed to moment of ignition, whilst Amperes are needed to maintain ICP is not degrading into CCP plasma. Here resonance is the best method because current in first and amperage in second version is mildly accomodating to actual that parameter demand at that NOT loosing the energy and not creating the much of heating.